# Find a solution for $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+f(x+1)=x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

Title says all. If $f$ is an analytic function on the real line, and $f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+f(x+1)=x$, what, if any, is a possible solution for $f(x)$?

Additionally, what are any solutions for $f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-f(x+1)=x$?

Comment: Do you have ideas yourself on how to proceed?

Comment: As mentioned below, I was thinking of symbolically writing down the coefficients for the power series around the golden ratio. But it seems to be a blind alley.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Examples maybe userful.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer but maybe something to consider for your second functional equation,

Let $\phi$ denote the golden ratio so that we have $\frac{1}{\phi}+1=\phi$

Then by the second functional equation if we set $x=\frac{1}{\phi}$ we have:

$$f(\phi)-f(\frac{1}{\phi}+1)=\frac{1}{\phi}$$
$$f(\phi)-f(\phi)=\frac{1}{\phi}$$
$$0=\frac{1}{\phi}$$

Which obviously isn't true so $f(x)$ isn't properly defined at $x=\phi$

---

In addition either $f(x)$ isn't analytic at $x=0$ or we must have that:

$$f(x)\sim -x$$

Because under the substitution $x\rightarrow x-1$ we have:

$$f(\frac{1}{x-1})-f(x)=x-1$$
$$-f(x)=x-1-f(\frac{1}{x-1})$$
$$f(x)=-x+1+f(\frac{1}{x-1})$$
$$f(x)=-x+O(1)$$

Where $\lim_{x\to\infty}1+f(\frac{1}{x-1})=1+f(0)=O(1)$ because by assumption $f$ is analytic at $0$ and therefore continuous at $0$, so we are able to interchange the limits.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints that might help...

1. $1/x = x+1$ when $x = \frac{\pm\sqrt{5}-1}2$
2. Differentiating gives: $-\frac{f'(1/x)}{x^2}+f'(1+x)=1$
3. Differentiating again gives: $f''(1+x)+\frac{f''(1/x)}{x^4}+\frac{2f'(1/x)}{x^3}=0$ - this can then be continued.
4. An "analytic function" has a Taylor series at any point that is convergent within a non-zero region around the point. So what would the Taylor series look like at the points given in hint 1?

ADDED:

A consideration of limits may also be useful. Indeed, with a substitution of $x=1/y-1$, you have $$f\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)+f\left(\frac1y\right)=\frac1y-1$$

We can then cancel out the $\frac1y$ term by first replacing $y$ with $x$, and limits from here may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah I had considered constructing the Taylor series around the golden ratio. However, it didn't seem to correspond to any closed-form function that I knew. Am I missing something obvious? Or is an infinite series the best that can be done?

Comment: To add to this, I couldn't find any closed form for the series coefficients either. So I could only come up with the first few terms for the infinite series.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a closed-form solution exists. But if one does, constructing some Taylor series terms might help you figure it out, even if it's not blatantly obvious. Also useful would be looking at the limits as $x\to\pm\infty$ and $x\to0$. Indeed, I think I'll edit the limits into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)+f\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)=\frac1x\\
f\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)+f\left(\frac{2x+1}{x+1}\right)-\frac1\phi=\frac{x}{x+1}-\frac1\phi\\
f\left(\frac{2x+1}{x+1}\right)+f\left(\frac{3x+2}{2x+1}\right)-\frac1\phi=\frac{x+1}{2x+1}-\frac1\phi$$
If $f$ is continuous at $\phi$, then 
$$f(x)=(\frac1x-\frac1{2\phi})-(\frac{x}{x+1}-\frac1{\phi})+(\frac{x+1}{2x+1}-\frac1{\phi})-...\\
=(\frac1x-\frac1{2\phi})-(1-\frac1{\phi}-\frac1{x+1})+(\frac12+\frac1{2(2x+1)}-\frac1{\phi})-...\\
=C+\frac1x+\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{2(2x+1)}+\frac1{3(3x+2)}+\frac1{5(5x+3)}+...
$$
for $C-\frac1{2\phi}-\frac1{1\times2}-\frac1{3\times5}-\frac1{8\times13}-...$

Comment: +1 Also perhaps if you make some assumptions on convergence you could subtract out a chunk of the series and replace it with $\ln(2)$ by using using the alternating series identity $\ln(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$

Comment: I think it will be 1/2,2/3,3/5,5/8, but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

For $f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+f(x+1)=x$ ,

$f\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)+f(x)=x-1$

$\because$ The general solution of $T(x+1)=\dfrac{1}{T(x)-1}$ is $T(x)=\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2\Theta(x)(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+\Theta(x)(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

$\therefore f\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}-1}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}\right)=\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}-1$

$f\left(\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^x(3-\sqrt5)+(-\sqrt5-1)^x(3+\sqrt5)}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}\right)=\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^x(3-\sqrt5)+(-\sqrt5-1)^x(3+\sqrt5)}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}$

$f\left(\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}{\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^x(\sqrt5-1)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(-\sqrt5-1)^x(\sqrt5+1)^2}{2}}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}\right)=\dfrac{\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^x(\sqrt5-1)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(-\sqrt5-1)^x(\sqrt5+1)^2}{2}}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}$

$f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+2(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}\right)=\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}}{2(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+2(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}$

$f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}\right)=\Theta(x)(-1)^x+\sum\limits_x\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}}{2(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+2(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Similarly, for $f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-f(x+1)=x$ ,

$f\left(\dfrac{2(\sqrt5-1)^x+2(-\sqrt5-1)^x}{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}\right)=\Theta(x)+\sum\limits_x\dfrac{(\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}+(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+2}}{2(\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}+2(-\sqrt5-1)^{x+1}}$ , where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at $f(1/x)+f(x+1)=x$. My assumption is that you mean a function defined and analytic at every point on the real line. If so, then there is no such function.

You would have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(1/x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(x-f(x+1)\right)\\
&=-f(1)
\end{align}
$$

And then:
$$
\begin{align}
f(0)&=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(1/x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-f(x+1)\right)&\Big(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)&=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-f(1)\Big)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}(x)+f(1)
\end{align}
$$

So $f(0)$ does not exist. Now, if you wanted a function that is analytic on the positive reals, then that would be something else.