# Fibonacci-related sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers

Related to this question [Find a solution for $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+f(x+1)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633664/find-a-solution-for-f1-xf1x-x), what is this sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}-\frac1{\phi}\right)$$
where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number and $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$ is the golden ratio.
It is the (negative of the) sum of all the gaps, because the ratio alternates above and below the golden ratio.

Comment: Not an answer of course, but interestingly, $$\frac{\phi - 16}{\pi}+4$$ differs from the numerical value by only about $10^{-7}$.

Comment: Due to its alternating nature, the term $-\dfrac1\phi$ can be omitted. Also, $$S=-0.5779217972676187477988879656556639\ldots$$

Comment: With a bit of work one can show that the sum can be written $$-\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{F_n\varphi^n}\;.$$

Comment: @Lucian: if you omit the $\frac1\phi$, the terms don't go to $0$.

Comment: @robjohn: You can group the terms in pairs, and use some identities involving Fibonacci numbers to simplify the new expression. Then the $-\dfrac1\phi$ goes away.

Comment: @Lucian: Yeah, so far, I've gotten it to $$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{F_{2k}\,F_{2k+1}}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac5{L_{4n+1}-1}$$

Comment: I have a feeling that a closed form may require a theta function.

Comment: A curious fact is that this is the negative of $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\phi\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the work on this question.

Comment: Alternative form: $$-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{\varphi^{2n}+(-1)^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: Another alternate form
$$\frac{1}{\phi} - \sqrt{5}\left(L(\phi^{-2}) - 2( L(\phi^{-4}) - L(\phi^{-8}))\right)$$

where $L(\beta)$ is a [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) which can be computable using the [q-polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) $\psi_\beta$ (`QPolyGamma[]` on WA):
$$L(\beta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\beta^n}{1-\beta^n} = \frac{\psi_\beta(1) + \log(1-\beta)}{\log \beta}$$

Comment: 1. $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( \frac{(-1)^nF_n}{F_{n+1}}) = \frac{(-1)^n n F_n}{F_{n+1}} \; $$ 
 2. $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{\phi} = \frac{(-1)^n -1}{2 \phi}$$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Note:* A lot of nice information is already given in the comment section to OPs question. Some aspects of my answer are stated there, so that this answer can be seen as *supplement to the comment section*.

First of all: I went through some papers regarding *reciprocal series of Fibonacci sums* and it seems there is *no closed formula* for OPs series. Arguments for this statement are given below.

> We can write OPs series as:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\phi}\right) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

since

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}&(-1)^n\left(\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)\\
> &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{2N}(-1)^n\left(\frac{F_n}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)\\
> &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{F_{2n}}{F_{2n+1}}-\frac{F_{2n-1}}{F_{2n}}\right)\\
> &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{F_{2n}^2-F_{2n-1}F_{2n+1}}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}\\
> &=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{-1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}\tag{2}\\
> &= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}
> \end{align*}

In (2) we use *[Cassini's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)* $F_{n}^2-F_{n-1}F_{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}$.

It's easy to see that the series

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}
\end{align*}
is absolutely convergent (see e.g. *[A.F. Horadam (1986)](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/26-2/horadam.pdf)*). So, convergence of OPs series follows due to
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}$.

> Now we put the focus at the series:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

and observe that according to [S. Rabinowitz (1999)](http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/reciprocalFSums.pdf) there is *no known simple solution* for the following series

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{F}_N=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n},\qquad
\mathbb{G}_N=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{F_n},\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\mathbb{K}_N=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}
\end{align*}

> The series (3) is *non-alternating* and *structurally similar* to $\mathbb{K}_N$. So, if there are no new insights since this paper was written, it's seems plausible that there is also no closed formula for (3) available.

What can we do? One way is to try to express other more complex reciprocal series of Fibonacci sums as expressions based upon the *building blocks* $\mathbb{F}_N,\mathbb{G}_N$ and $\mathbb{K}_N$. Another possibility is to express them via other *standard* functions:

> The investigation of $\mathbb{F}_N$ by *Catalan* 1883 and earlier by *Lucas* 1878 was done by dividing $\mathbb{F}_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n}$
>
> - into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n-1}}$ expressible in terms of *Jacobian Elliptic Functions* and
> - into$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}}$ expressible in terms of *Lambert series*
>
> *Landau* elaborated based on Catalan's result presentation in terms of *Theta Functions* (see [A.F. Horadam](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/26-2/horadam.pdf)).

These are the *typically* used building blocks to express the reciprocal series of Fibonacci sums. Focussing on series of *order two* we find e.g. in [A solution to a tantalizing problem](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/24-4/almkvist.pdf) by G. Almkvist (1984) 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}^2}=
\frac{5}{24}\left(1+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\frac{\vartheta_{1}^{\prime\prime}}{\vartheta_{1}^{\prime}}\right)\qquad\qquad
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n-1}^2}=
-\frac{5}{8\pi^2}\frac{\vartheta_{3}^{\prime\prime}}{\vartheta_{3}}
\end{align*}

a representations in terms of Theta functions or in *[R.S. Melham (1998)](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/37-3/melham1.pdf)* we find

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_n^2},\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}^2},\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n-1}^2}
\end{align*}
expressed in terms of *Lambert series*

\begin{align*}
L(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1-x^n}\qquad |x|< 1
\end{align*}

and also in *[R.Andre-Jeannin (1988)](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/28-3/andre-jeannin.pdf)* we find

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}
=2\sqrt{5}\left[L\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-2L\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)+2L\left(\frac{47-21\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right]+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}

in terms of Lambert series. We follow this Ansatz imitate his proof of Lemma 2 and express the series (3) also in terms of Lambert series.

> The following is valid
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}&=\sqrt{5}\left[L(\psi^2)-2L(\psi^4)+2L(\psi^8)\right]+\psi\\
> &=\sqrt{5}\left[L\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-2L\left(\frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
> +2L\left(\frac{47-21\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right]+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}
> \end{align*}

We use $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=-\frac{1}{\phi}$ and observe

\begin{align*}
\phi F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}&=\phi \frac{\phi^{2n+1}-\psi^{2n+1}}{\phi-\psi}+\frac{\phi^{2n}-\psi^{2n}}{\phi-\psi}\\
&=\frac{1}{\phi-\psi}\left[\phi\left(\phi^{2n+1}+\frac{1}{\phi^{2n+1}}\right)+\left(\phi^{2n}-\frac{1}{\phi^{2n}}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\phi-\psi}\left(\phi^{2n+2}+\phi^{2n}\right)\\
&=\frac{\phi^{2n+1}}{\phi-\psi}\left(\phi+\frac{1}{\phi}\right)\\
&=\phi^{2n+1}
\end{align*}

This implies

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\phi^{2n}F_{2n}}+\frac{1}{\phi^{2n+1}F_{2n+1}}&=\frac{\phi F_{2n+1}+F_{2n}}{\phi F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}
=\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}
\end{align*}

> And we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\phi^n F_n}
> &=\frac{1}{\phi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\phi^{2n}F_{2n}}+\frac{1}{\phi^{2n+1}F_{2n+1}}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{\phi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> According to Lemma 3 in  [R.Andre-Jeannin (1988)](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/28-3/andre-jeannin.pdf) the following identity is valid:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\phi^n F_{n}}=\sqrt{5}\left[L(\psi^2)-2L(\psi^4)+2L(\psi^8)\right]\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing the RHS of (4) and (5) and observing that $\frac{1}{\phi}=-\psi$ the claim follows.

*Note:* Some additional information regarding *closed formulae*. In [Summation of infinite Fibonacci Series](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/7-2/brousseau1.pdf) by brother A. Brousseau (1969) we find some identities of reciprocal sums of order two. One of them is the alternating sum

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{F_nF_{n+k}}=\frac{1}{F_k}\left[k\phi^{-1}-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{F_{j-1}}{F_j}\right]\qquad k\geq 1
\end{align*}

We further see that the non-alternating series 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+k}}\qquad k\geq 1
\end{align*}
has a closed formula when $k$ is *even* and when $k$ is odd it is expressible as $a+b\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}$ with $a,b$ rational numbers, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}$ is used as building block.

> Some examples:
>
> \begin{align*}
> &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+2}}=1\qquad&\qquad
> &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+3}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{4}\\
> \\
> &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+4}}=
> \frac{7}{18}\qquad&\qquad
> &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+3}}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+1}}-\frac{17}{150}
> \end{align*}

Comment: @Michael: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. Best regards,